# Get rid of the hyphen (-2) at the end of URL in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

One of the pages of my Wordpress website has the hyphen and 2 at the end of the URL (mydomain.org/publications-2). I've tried to change this using the option 'Permalink --> Edit' but it does not save the updates. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: what created the publication post type? a theme ? a plugin? you? not a post type, a normal page?

Answer (score 0):

In your Wordpress Dashboard go to pages.
When you are there select the page that has the hyphen. When there click on edit permalink left on top. This should work.

> Notice:
>
> Make sure that the page you are changing the name to doesnt already
>   exist. If this is the case the name wont change.

Comment: Thanks so much, @kevin.a . I tried this but the name of the URL still does not change. I've also checked and there is no other page with the same name. Also, when I enter mydomain.org/publications in browser, it redirects to mydomain.org/publications-2

Comment: Are you using a redirect plugin or is there something in your .htacess file making it redirect